# Laying out fire UIViews in a row with Autolayout Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, visual-format-language

So, I want to use the `Autolayout Visual Format Language` to place 4 `UIViews` in horizontal rows (from top to bottom, like keyboard rows)... but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be working as expected, as my views seem to wind up in a stack on top of each other... Probably due to a mistake in the Visual Format...

So I have my 4 `UIViews` as such:

```
UIView *rowOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[rowOne setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[rowOne setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:rowOne];

UIView *rowTwo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 50, 50)];
[rowTwo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[rowTwo setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:rowTwo];

UIView *rowThree = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 50, 50)];
[rowThree setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[rowThree setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:rowThree];

UIView *rowFour = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 50, 50)];
[rowFour setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[rowFour setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:rowFour];
```

I add them to a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(rowOne, rowTwo, rowThree, rowFour);
```

I create the constraints:

```
NSString *rowsVerticalConstraintsString = @"V:|-[rowOne][rowTwo][rowThree][rowFour]-|";
NSString *rowOneHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowOne]-|";
NSString *rowTwoHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowTwo]-|";
NSString *rowThreeHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowThree]-|";
NSString *rowFourHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowFour]-|";

NSArray *rowsVerticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:rowsVerticalConstraintsString
                                                                           options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views];

NSArray *rowOneHorizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:rowTwoHorizontalConstraintString
                                                                              options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];

NSArray *rowTwoHorizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:rowOneHorizontalConstraintString
                                                                              options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];

NSArray *rowThreeHorizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:rowThreeHorizontalConstraintString
                                                                              options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];

NSArray *rowFourHorizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:rowFourHorizontalConstraintString
                                                                              options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];
```

and add the constraints to the view:

```
[self.view addConstraints:rowsVerticalConstraints];
[self.view addConstraints:rowOneHorizontalConstraint];
[self.view addConstraints:rowTwoHorizontalConstraint];
[self.view addConstraints:rowThreeHorizontalConstraint];
[self.view addConstraints:rowFourHorizontalConstraint];
```

The behaviour that I would expect would be that the views are laid out side-by-side vertically and stretched horizontally, but they seem to overlay each other...

Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: Try to replace `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]` with simple `[UIView new]`. And options to `NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note:when using auto layout,initWithFrame have no compact

Your layout constraints does not have height constraints.You may set 4 views have same height

```
NSString *rowsVerticalConstraintsString = @"V:|-[rowOne(==rowTwo)][rowTwo][rowThree(==rowTwo)][rowFour(==rowTwo)]-|";
```

Then screenshot

[image]

Also,you can set width to be 150,height 50

```
 NSString *rowsVerticalConstraintsString = @"V:|-[rowOne(50)][rowTwo(50)][rowThree(50)][rowFour(50)]";
NSString *rowOneHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowOne(150)]";
NSString *rowTwoHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowTwo(150)]";
NSString *rowThreeHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowThree(150)]";
NSString *rowFourHorizontalConstraintString = @"H:|-[rowFour(150)]";
```

Then screenshot

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!